# Did I hear "indiscreet or in discreet vs indiscrete or in discrete"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, expressions, vocabulary

I was watching "Miss Marple" on pbs and there is one conversation between inspector and a lady as one of house member. A lady was showing specific room to an inspector who is looking for some pictures as an evidence.
"Should I leave you, if you want to be in discreet?"
Or, "Should I leave you, if you want to be indiscreet?"
Did I hear something wrong?

Another question I have is, is there any different meaning between "discreet" and "discrete"? I looked up dictionary but I am not sure because one of dictionary explain its same but some are stating difference. Thank you

Comment: Try googling "discreet vs. discrete," there are many many resources explaining the difference between those two words.

Comment: The opposite of _discrete_ is typically _non-discrete_, for this reason. It's ***good*** to have lots of different redundant affixes.

Comment: @JohnLawler I disagree with your typical example. A majority of the usages I've seen have been *indiscrete*.

Comment: @press Tilty I found this from Merriam webster. Thanks. http://www.merriam-webster.com/blog/discreet-discrete-definitions-examples.htm

"Which should you use? Remember that in discrete, the t separates the e's, so discrete means "separate." For "unobtrusive", use discreet."

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that one can be *in discrete/discreet* as it's not a state that one can be in.

I would assume, given the context, that it would be **indiscreet**.